# trying to get Arabic word in Nextjs Router - Params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to filter the data and i pass the search value to the router, but the search Value is in Arabic and this is what i get.
[image: Arabic Search Value here]

however, when i try the same thing in English i get the required result.

[image: English Search Value]

what do i need to do to get the filtered data in Arabic?

Here is my search box

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!search) return;
    router.push(`./SearchMeal/${search}`);
  };
return (
    <div className="xl:flex hidden justify-between w-[90%] my-5 pt-6 px-2 pb-2 ">
      
      <div className="flex-1 ">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="">
          <input
            value={search}
            onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="بحث عن وصفة"
            className="p-2 border-accent outline-none rounded-md text-center placeholder-gray-500  bg-slate-100 "
          />
          <div className="flex justify-center mt-2">
            <button
              disabled={!search}
              type="submit"
              className="p-2 w-[80%] border-none outline-none rounded-md bg-accent text-primary font-bold text-base cursor-pointer disabled:cursor-none disabled:text-gray-100 disabled:bg-gray-400"
            >
              بحث
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

and here is my search result page

```
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const SearchMeal = ({ params }) => {
  
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(params.searchTerm);
return (
    <div className="flex flex-col  w-full self-center justify-center border border-solid">
      <input
        value={searchTerm}
        className="w-1/2 flex self-center mt-5 rounded-md p-2 text-center"
        type="text"
        placeholder="بحث عن وصفة"
        autoFocus
        onChange={(event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        {MEALS.filter((val) => {
          if (params.searchTerm == "") {
            return val;
          } else if (
            val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
          ) {
            return val;
          }
        }).map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="flex justify-center">
              <MealsListCard mealsList={item} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchMeal;
```

when i filter the data without passing the search value to the router, it works fine and i get the filtered data, but itis not working when pushing it with the router.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use query params for that purpose.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!search) return;
    router.replace({ query: { search } });
  }
```

and you can read that change using

```
router.query.search
```

It will return the data with correct formatting

Answer (score 0):

here is how i fixed it.
1- i changed the button to a link and removed the handle submit function.
here is the updated search bar

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
   return (
    <div className="xl:flex hidden justify-between w-[90%] my-5 pt-6 px-2 pb-2">
  <div className="flex-1 ">
    <form className="">
      <input
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="بحث عن وصفة"
        className="p-2 border-accent outline-none rounded-md text-center placeholder-gray-500  bg-slate-100 "
      />
      <div className="flex justify-center mt-2">
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: "./SearchMeal",
            query: { search: search },
          }}
          className={` ${
            search.length <= 0
              ? "no-underline text-center p-2 w-[80%] border-none outline-none rounded-md font-bold text-base cursor-none text-gray-100 bg-gray-400"
              : "no-underline text-center p-2 w-[80%] border-none outline-none rounded-md bg-accent text-primary font-bold text-base cursor-pointer disabled:cursor-none "
          }`}
        >
          بحث
        </Link>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>);};

export default SearchBar;
```

then created another component search box

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import MealsListCard from "../../components/UI/Card/MealsListCard";
const SearchBox = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const searchWord = searchParams.get("search");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(searchWord);
  return (
<div className="flex flex-col  w-full self-center justify-center border border-solid">
  <input
    value={searchTerm}
    className="w-1/2 flex self-center mt-5 rounded-md p-2 text-center"
    type="text"
    placeholder="بحث عن وصفة"
    autoFocus
    onChange={(event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
  />
  <div>
    {MEALS.filter((val) => {
      if (searchParams.search == "") {
        return val;
      } else if (
        val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return val;
      }
    }).map((item) => {
      return (
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <MealsListCard mealsList={item} />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>);};

export default SearchBox;
```

and finally the search result page in server side not client side

```
import SearchBox from "../components/SearchBox/page";
const SearchMeal = () => {
   return (
    <div>
     <SearchBox />
    </div>
  );
 };

export default SearchMeal;
```

and finally, i got the result as shown in the image below
[image]